# Suppose |a| = 2, for all a in G and |G| >= 4. Show that |G| is congruent to 0 (mod 4)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Because the order of a is 2, |G| must be an even number because |a| divides |G|. So 2 divides |G|.

So, we assume |a| = 2 for all a in G, |G| >= 4, and |G| is even.
We must show |G| is congruent to 0 (mod 4), which implies that |G| is divisible by 4.

I'm not sure how to show this. Does it have something to do with the fact that every element in G is of order 2? If so, I'm not sure where to go from there either.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: How can it happen that every element of $G$ has order $2$ ? What about the identity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's no prime number $p$ different from 2 that divides $|G|$, because in that case there must exist an element of order $p$ in $G$ by Cauchy Theorem.

Then the order of $G$ must be a power of $2$ greater than 4 and consequently $|G| \equiv 0\mod 4$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $p||G|$ then $G$ contains an element of order $p$.